# Convert JSON object structure to html input elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to create dynamically hidden elements with name - value to store a JSON object.

For this input:

```
json_structure = {
    'var_1':'value_1',
    'var_2': {
        'var_2_1':'value_2_1',
        'var_2_2':'value_2_2'
    },
    'var_3': 'value_3'
};
```

should have

```
<input type="hidden" name="var_1" value="value_1" />
<input type="hidden" name="var_2[var_2_1]" value="value_2_1" />
<input type="hidden" name="var_2[var_2_2]" value="value_2_2" />
<input type="hidden" name="var_3" value="value_3" />
```

**EDIT1**
Here is my example, but works only for a one level object. For multiple levels need to make a recursive function to build the entire structure.

```
for(var key in json_structure ) {
        if(json_structure .hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
            hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
            hiddenField.setAttribute("name", key);
            hiddenField.setAttribute("value", json_structure [key]);

            form.appendChild(hiddenField);
         }
    }
```

Is there a way to do this in a JavaScript or jQuery function which makes this easier?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: yes, i will add a short code to demonstrate

Comment: Please add what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use some recursive approach to generate the input code where use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method for iterating over the object properties.

```js
var json_structure = {
  'var_1': 'value_1',
  'var_2': {
    'var_2_1': 'value_2_1',
    'var_2_2': 'value_2_2'
  },
  'var_3': 'value_3'
};

// function forr generating input
function genInput(obj, res, prefix) {
  // get all the object keys and iterate
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(k) {
    // generate the name with prefix
    var name = prefix ? prefix + '[' + k + ']' : k;

    // check property value is object
    // in case its object call the function recursively
    if (typeof obj[k] == 'object')
      // skip null by checking value is truthy
      obj[k] && genInput(obj[k], res, name);

    // else generate the input and push into the output array  
    else
      res.push('<input type="hidden" name="' + name + '" value="' + obj[k] + '"/>')
  })

  // finally return the array generated
  return res;
}

console.log(
  genInput(json_structure, [])
)
```

---

For generating DOM element and updating either you can use jQuery with the above code or with pure java do something like this.

```js
var json_structure = {
  'var_1': 'value_1',
  'var_2': {
    'var_2_1': 'value_2_1',
    'var_2_2': 'value_2_2'
  },
  'var_3': 'value_3'
};

function genInput(obj, form, prefix) {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(k) {
    var name = prefix ? prefix + '[' + k + ']' : k;
    if (typeof obj[k] == 'object') {
      obj[k] && genInput(obj[k], form, name);
    } else {
      var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
      hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
      hiddenField.setAttribute("name", name);
      hiddenField.setAttribute("value", obj[k]);
      form.appendChild(hiddenField);
    }
  })
}

genInput(json_structure, document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0])
```

```html
<form></form>
```

With jQuery :

```js
var json_structure = {
  'var_1': 'value_1',
  'var_2': {
    'var_2_1': 'value_2_1',
    'var_2_2': 'value_2_2'
  },
  'var_3': 'value_3'
};

// function forr generating input
function genInput(obj, res, prefix) {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(k) {
    var name = prefix ? prefix + '[' + k + ']' : k;
    if (typeof obj[k] == 'object')
      obj[k] && genInput(obj[k], res, name);
    else
      res.push('<input type="hidden" name="' + name + '" value="' + obj[k] + '"/>')
  })
  return res;
}

// append the array of html string
$('form').append(genInput(json_structure, []))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form></form>
```

Comment: Thank you for your code. This works OK for the provided example. An json object  can also contains arrays as value instead strings or objects.

Comment: My intention is to find if already exist a function in javascript or jquery which cand do this. I see that my question is not concise.

Comment: @vasilenicusor :  i think, there is no such predefined function

Comment: yah, I will make a full solution and I will come with the result. Thank you

Comment: I will accept your solution with a minor change : `if (typeof obj[k] == 'object' && obj[k] != null)` instead of  `if (typeof obj[k] == 'object')`

Comment: @vasilenicusor :  do you want to skip `null` or want to generate input with null value?

Comment: is ok with skip `null`

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need jQuery in this case.

Here's a slightly different version.

```js
var json_structure = {
    'var_1':'value_1',
    'var_2': {
        'var_2_1':'value_2_1',
        'var_2_2':'value_2_2'
    },
    'var_3': 'value_3'
};

function createHiddenInput(name, value) {
  var hiddenInput = document.createElement("input");
  hiddenInput.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
  hiddenInput.setAttribute("name", name);
  hiddenInput.setAttribute("value", value);
  document.body.appendChild(hiddenInput);
  console.log(hiddenInput);
}

function generateInputs(structure, prepend) {
  for (var propertyKey in structure) {
    if (structure.hasOwnProperty(propertyKey)) {
      var property = json_structure[propertyKey]
      if (typeof property === 'object') {
        generateInputs(property, propertyKey)
      } else {
        var name = prepend ? prepend + '[' + propertyKey + ']' : property;
        createHiddenInput(name, propertyKey)
      }
    }
  }
}

generateInputs(json_structure)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nice, with Vanilla JS.

Comment: is same as previous answer